# Insufficient Logging information in AWS MQTT broker/Rule invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am trying to publish a  message to MQTT topic.

I have  written a Lambda function, which gets triggered when a message is published to the MQTT topic.

I am sending a message in the JSON format. If the JSON payload is correct, the lambda is triggered correctly.

If the JSON payload is invalid ( e.g. one double quote " is incorrect - ” in json payload) the lambda function doesn't get triggered.

No error message is displayed in the cloudwatch logs. It is very difficult to debug this issue.

I think when the payload is invalid, a message should be logged to cloudwatch that the payload is invalid.

Is there any better way to debug this issue?

Comment: What is the rule that you are using?

Comment: The Rule extracts the device information published in JSON format on a MQTT topic and triggers a lambda.             select field1, field2, field3 from 'topic'